# Couldn't find a square in an image using open cv python

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, python

1. Square detection in an image using `cv2.rectangle()`
2. image Using `drawcontours()`, I can see multiple points
3. Original image

- I am able to detect two out of three squares.
- The problem is that this is just a part of a very wide image, and only one square is undetectable. One big green box is missing and it is not detectable.

[image: Square detection in an image]

[image: Using Draw contour, I can see multiple points]

[image: Original image]

- Can you help in square detection?
- I have used the below code:

```py
    def getContours(img,imgContour):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

    # image_number = 0
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        # cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 255), 7)
        peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * peri, True)
        print(len(approx))
        # if len(approx) == 4:
        x , y , w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        ar = w/h                
        if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05:
            cv2.rectangle(imgContour, (x , y ), (x + w , y + h ), (0, 255, 0), 5)

    def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)
    # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)
    # return the edged image
    return edged

    imagePath = "image3.jpg"
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    imgContour = image.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
    auto = auto_canny(blurred)
    getContours(auto,imgContour)
```

Comment: You mean you have trouble finding contours around the top left square, right?

Comment: @ElyasKarimi Yes, I wish to detect the whole square in one go and not multiple squares. Once I detect the square I would like to read the text inside it with the help of OCR. Could you please suggest what should I do in order to detect a perfect square?